# Как запустить скайп 7 без обновления?

Tags: windows, windows-10, skype, обновление

При запуске Skype 7.41.0.101 выдаёт окно с кнопками <kbd>Обновить Skype</kbd> и <kbd>Выйти</kbd>. При этом известно, что на другом компьютере эта версия отлично работает. Пробовал некоторые ключи запуска, но не помогло. Предполагаю, что дело может быть во включенности автообновления в настройках, но до настроек добраться не могу, поскольку есть только это окно. Что и где надо поменять?

[image: скриншот]

PS: Я скоро систему буду переустанавливать, попробую там поставить классический сначала ([оффлайновый инсталлятор](https://download.skype.com/msi/SkypeSetup_7.41.0.101.msi)), но, возможно, тоже придётся что-то настроить?

Comment: а если на крестик?

Comment: @Grundy, закрывается полностью.

Comment: Последняя версия 7-й ветки лежит всегда тут: https://www.skype.com/go/getskype-msi, если чё.

Comment: @donRumata, не вижу инсталлятора по твоей ссылке - там вообще 404. Моя ссылка когда-то с такой страницы и была получена.

Comment: Блин, уроды, опять поломали. Раньше работало. :(

Comment: @donRumata, странно, что ещё сам msi не удалили. Ссылка-то на их сайт. Кстати поправочка, она не с той страницы, а я отследил, откуда их онлайн-инсталлятор скачивает полный дистрибутив.

Comment: в реестре запрещается, надо гуглить "skype regedit auto update"

Comment: так вроде они хотели отключать седьмую версию вообще

Comment: @Grundy, работает на другом компьютере, значит не отключили.

Comment: В меня на вин7 заставили обновиться, на вин10 продолжает работать. Скайп кеширует какие-то ответы от сервера, и моментально при старте показывает это окно. Если удалить папку DataRv в %user%\AppData\Roaming\Skype, то он думает некоторое время вначале снова скачивая что-то сюда.

Comment: @Zergatul, у меня наоборот, на десятке показывает, на семёрке работает. Я попробовал его с ключами `/removable` и `/datapath` запустить - ввёл логин, пароль, выслал уведомление на почту, подтвердил, после чего ом мне взял и выдал то же окно :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, майки официально продолжают поддерживать 7-ю ветку. Новость даже где-то была, что не всем нравится 8 и куча людей требуют 7.

Comment: @donRumata, было когда-то, но вроде уже закончили? В любом случае, как его запустить-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html поищи им слово "skype". Вдруг чё интересное найдёшь. И на том, где всё пашет - тоже. А потом диффни.

Comment: @donRumata, тогда уж проще удалить всё :)

Comment: Тут вопрос что важнее: чтобы работало или докопаться до истины.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88649/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-don-rumata).